# Elasticsearch - Given a query_string with a wildcard, can I aggregate on the matched term?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm about to describe the use case for a terms aggregation and the reason why mappings should be properly configured but given the state of our cluster, neither of these are options.

I'm doing full-text searching on a terabyte of raw log data and trying to do some counts on the specific terms being matched.

Given a query string like `192.168.0.*` I'm finding documents that reference terms like `192.168.0.12` somewhere in the body as expected. *The specific field is not consistent.*

What I'd like to do is an aggregation on the term that was found. If ES returns 100 documents in which `192.168.0.12` was found, there should be a counter that reflects this (`192.168.0.12: 100`). Similarly, if 50 documents were found for `192.168.0.254` I'd expect to see `192.168.0.254: 50`.

Given the scale and timing this has to be done in Elasticsearch, not sideloaded and iterated application-side. Is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you will need to define your **mapping** something like this

```
"IP_ADDRESS": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "fields": {
              "raw":{
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
        }
```

So the searching will be on **IP_ADDRESS.raw** and term aggregation will be on **IP_ADDRESS**

```
{
  "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "default_field": "IP_ADDRESS.raw",
        "query": "192.168.0.*"
      }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "count_term": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "IP_ADDRESS",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but messing with mappings is not an option, nor is running a terms aggregation. The fieldname is not consistent.

Comment: What's the field tyoe for all fields on which you would like to run this match n want the count ? If they are all text, then just the match query n no. Of hits will give the desired results.